# Will Ubuntu+KVM support an old Intel QuadCore Q8300 + Asus P5QPL

Tags: drivers, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to convert this machine into a mini VM server

The processor is Intel Q8300 QuadCore which IFAIK supports virtualization. 
The motherboard is Asus P5QPL-AM.
It has Intel G41 chipset, X4500 acccelerator, integrated Gbit Lan
8GB memory + SATA SSD drive

In the BIOS I see an option to enable HW Virtualization

My question is whether KVM on Ubuntu will support this processor, and will it support para-virtualization on a win10/ubunutu GuestOS for accelerated network & storage & video performance

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly there are different versions of the Q8300 CPU. Intel decided to enable virtualization in between. I was wondering but I am running one with VT enabled. 
You can enable HW Virtualization in BIOS and check the VT flag using:

```
 #cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep vmx**
```

Win10 support can be checked here: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Guest_Support_Status